# out-параметр + cast

Tags: c#

Я часто использую такую схему.

Есть у меня словарь, в котором тип значения - это некоторый базовый тип (тип ключа не важен), а на выходе метод должен вернуть конкретный подкласс этого типа. Для получения значения из словаря я использую метод `TryGetValue`. Этот метод имеет `out`-параметр, имеющий тип значения словаря. Соответственно, мне необходимо объявить переменную этого типа, а на выходе из метода её кастовать.

Можно ли написать что-то вроде:

```
MyRetType value;
my_dic.TryGetValue(myKey, out (MyBaseType)value);
```

Такой вариант не компилируется.

Comment: Сперва вытащите, потом кастуйте.

Comment: Виталик прав, только для этого прийдётся реализовывать __implicit__ или __explicit__ операторы привидения родительского класса к дочернему.

Comment: Виталик, я так и делаю. Просто надеялся, есть способ поэстетичнее.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Пост Эрика Липперта, объясняющий данное поведение: "[Почему в ref и out параметрах нет вариантности типов?](https://web.archive.org/web/20140512033820/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ruericlippert/archive/2009/09/21/ref-out.aspx)".